# Highcharts Dynamic Column color based on data comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

Here's a snippet of what I'm trying to do, basically I have 2 values I'm feeding into the graph I want to change the color of the column based on the comparison. Basically if value is greater than target be green, else be blue. But the target values are different for each column.

```
column: {
                zones: [{
                    value: data[1] >= data[2],
                    color: 'green'
                }, {
                    color: 'blue'
                }]
            }
```

Comment: It seems that you want to change color of point - column based on point's value - you could set color per point in data. Parse your data to include info about color and use that instead of zones.

Answer (score 0):

zones is a data array, and therefore the calculation won't happen procedurally.  You'd need to compute that outside of the array, for example create a function to do the computation and call that to return the color:

```
column: {
            zones: [{
                color: getComputedColor(data)
            }, {
                color: 'blue'
            }]
        }
....

function getComputedColor(data)
{   if (data[1] >= data[2])
       return "green";
    return "blue";
}
```